# Debian command-not-found error - local variable 'cnf' referenced before assignment

Tags: debian, bugs

After fresh installing Debian buster OS and
Package: command-not-found

running command:

```
$ curl
Could not find the database of available applications, run update-command-not-found as root to fix this
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
http://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.7.3 final 0
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
Exception information:

local variable 'cnf' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 23, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 93, in main
    if not cnf.advise(args[0], options.ignore_installed) and not options.no_failure_msg:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnf' referenced before assignment
```

Issuing `update-command-not-found` as root does not fix the problem.
There is bug report, but seems no fix yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not intuitive, but error goes away immediately after `apt update`:

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Contents (deb) [36.1 MB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Contents (deb) [42.3 kB]
Fetched 36.2 MB in 7s (5,009 kB/s)                                                                                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

# curl

Command 'curl' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install curl
```

PS. For those curious, the reason for that is missing db upon fresh install:

```
ls -l /var/lib/command-not-found
total 0
```

and after `apt update` we have:

```
ls -l /var/lib/command-not-found
total 2504
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2560000 Jul 29 12:34 commands.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     983 Jul 29 12:34 commands.db.metadata
```

Comment: Yep, worked for me. Do you know why that works, if it somehow fixes permissions on the db file (re the other answer) or something else?

Comment: please upvote if this helped. Just checked fresh install to make sure, after install the db is missing, and apt update builds the db.

Answer (score 3):

Change permission at

```
sudo chmod o+r /var/lib/command-not-found/commands.db*
```

but before that

Check permission variable state information

```
ls -l /var/lib/command-not-found

total 2588

-rw-r----- 1 root root 2834432 Dec 18 05:25 commands.db
-rw-r----- 1 root root    4712 Dec 18 05:25 commands.db.metadata
```

It should be:

```
ls -l /var/lib/command-not-found

total 2588

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2641920 Jan 16 00:27 commands.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1175 Jan 16 00:27 commands.db.metadata
```